# EditText in multi-color

Tags: android, android-layout

I am working on an Android application.

Now I want take input from user into an EditText.
I want display the text after the last fullstop in black color and text before  last full stop in red color.

For example, If user types below sentence in EditText:

```
'my name is john.I am from India.I Love Android'
```

I want to show the 'I love Android ' in black and first parts of the sentence in red.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listen to changes in text by:

```
    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() { 
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { 
            if (!colorHasSet) {
                makeColorText();
            }
            colorHasSet = false;
        }
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {}
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {}
    });
```

then declare a function to colorize text by using the tutorial which WebnetMobile linked to.

```
public void makeColorText() {
     SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(textEdit.getText());
    // customize ss here
    // ...
    colorHasSet = true;
    editText.setText(ss);
}
```

flag boolean variable `colorHasSet` should be defined to prevent stackOverflowException.

this is not a complete WYSIWYG editor with instant colored text, and you should do some hacks to make it complete and suitable to your needs, that is left to be done by yourself.

Comment: editText.setText(ss);..will call the addtextchangelistener again so the result will be an infinite loop

Comment: @sarath Yes, you are right. I added that boolean flag colorHasSet to prevent infinite loop. So, any change to text will cause only one time launch of `afterTextChanged()`

Comment: @yrajabi.. This solution makes a issue...please have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12526269/editing-edittext-is-working-strange

Answer (score 3):

Use `SpannableString` to apply attributes to your text. Here blog entry you may want to read: http://www.chrisumbel.com/article/android_textview_rich_text_spannablestring.

Comment: i dont want to settext. At the time of user entering test.it must happen. maY be Some listeners can do this I am not sure..

Comment: So you want WYSIWYG? No that easy - there's no built-in editor like this. The simplest approach would be to have `EditText` for user input and separate `TextView` for styled preview.

Comment: You can setup a listener to parse and add color to your text after 600 milliseconds of no input. Then set the colorized text onto the view and off you go.